# wireless card in place of an antenna/ hack a robot

Tags: gnuradio, software-defined-radio

My nephew has this toy robot and asked me to build a new remote for it. It's a "Cady Wida" robot from JJRC. When I opened it up, a tag inside said "40 MHz" and the board sported a "CHOB" IR sensor. I'm assuming the robot wants a 40MHz sideband from a 2.4 GHz center frequency.

So I fired up the RPI4 and "gnuradio" with the idea of poking around to make something happen. I don't want to invest in any new equipment, but I'm also new to SDR and haven't found any examples of people running SDR programs without external equipment. Why can't I use the 2.4 GHz signal my wireless card spits out and multiply that signal that with the 40MHz the robot wants? Anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't I use the 2.4 GHz signal my wireless card spits out

That wlan card produces a broadband wlan signal,

> and multiply that signal that with the 40MHz the robot wants?

Not a single tone you can mix with. Also, "multiply with 2.4 GHz" might be a tad harder to do cleanly enough than you think.

Also, how would that multiplication even help you? Still an analog signal afterwards, and not anywhere you can analyze it!

Anyway,

> I'm assuming the robot wants a 40MHz sideband from a 2.4 GHz center frequency.

Almost certainly not. That 40 MHz either describes the actual carrier frequency, or the frequency of an on-board quartz oscillator used as base to deliver some other clock that might pretty much be anything, or be completely unrelated.